# AWS Glue Job Failing With More Than One Executor?

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

I have an AWS glue job that reads from a glue catalog. The glue catalog is from s3 files with only 73 objects for a total size of 126.3 KB.

When the glue job runs I only have 200 rows of data however I run a lot of transformations on that data prior to running collect().
If I run the job with two workers (so only one executor) of size G1x the job is able to complete.

If I run the job with 10 workers of size G8x I get:

> An error occurred while calling o1043.collectToPython.
> java.lang.StackOverflowError

ExecutorLostFailure (executor 3 exited caused by one of the running tasks)

Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Attempted debugging that didn't work:

- Set partition size small (10) and large (100)
- Cache dataframe before running collect()
- Ensured security group had self referential all tcp inbound permissions
- Ensured subnet had enough ip addresses